# Search bar and log out option follows along with scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I have inserted a search bar and log out option into a web page I'm created. However, the problem is that when I scroll up and down, the search and scroll bar follow along with the page instead of staying in their place. I'm not sure why.

```css
.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header input[type=text] {
  padding: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.logout {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="logout" style="clear: both;">
    <a href="#logout"> Log out</a>
  </div>
  <img src="images/logo.jpeg" alt="The Open University logo">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Example Title</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Because `position:fixed;`

Comment: what should it be? I've tried position: relative and absolute

Comment: @j08691 i tried to remove the whole position and just have right and top, but it still moves

Comment: Where do you want it to appear? If you tried `absolute` it should have done exactly what you currently have but not scrolling with the page.

Comment: @j08691 just at the top right of the page, when i have it at right:10px and top 100px, its fine there. When I try fixed: absolute; it still moves a long with page :(

Comment: @j08691 ok never mind i got it, absolute works fine! I was looking at the wrong thing. Do you have any suggestions on how to make this responsive? I probably wouldn't want it to be in the top corner